# таблицы в oracle developer FOREIGN KEY and PRIMARY KEY

Tags: база-данных, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Student(  

    st_id NUMBER NOT NULL,  
    student_name VARCHAR(20),  
    student_surname VARCHAR(20),  
    student_email VARCHAR(20),  
    CONSTRAINT student_id PRIMARY KEY (st_id),  
    CONSTRAINT faculty_of_student FOREIGN KEY (facul_id) REFERENCES 
    faculty(faculty_id)
);

CREATE TABLE faculty(               

    facul_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
    faculty_name VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT faculty_id PRIMARY KEY (facul_id)
);
```

Нужно в таблице `student` создать столбец `faculty_of_student` с таблицы `faculty`.

Comment: ну так создайте. видите, вы в primary key пишите `primary key(st_id)` т.е. указываете имя объявленной ранее колонки. С форедженами то же самое, объявляете колонку `faculty_of_student NUMBER NOT NULL` и указываете ее в `FOREIGN KEY (faculty_of_student)` и так же в части на что ссылается, так же пишется имя колонки, а не ключа, т.е. `faculty(facul_id)`

Comment: пишет name is already used by an existing object line 10 column 13 то есть таблица faculty уже существует?

Comment: да, скорее всего. вы ее видимо уже создали. А если так то посмотрите с какой структурой вы ее создали. в ней то как раз ничего менять не надо. Только в таблице студентов добавить колонку и правильно написать имена в foreign.

Comment: Error starting at line 1 in command:
CREATE TABLE Student(
  st_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
  student_name VARCHAR(20),
  student_surname VARCHAR(20),
  student_email VARCHAR(20),
  faculty_of_student NUMBER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT student_id PRIMARY KEY (st_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (faculty_of_student) REFERENCES faculty(facul_id)
)
Error at Command Line:8 Column:46

Comment: А ошибка какая ? Опять что таблица уже существует ? Удалите все таблицы и создайте заново. Я прогнал у себя ваши create (с учетом последнего что вы написали) никаких ошибок, таблицы отлично создались.

Comment: список существующих таблиц можно посмотреть `select * from user_tables`; удалить таблицу можно `drop table Student;`

Answer (score 0):

Привет!
Попробуйте пересоздать структуру, используя набор команд:

```sql
drop table student;
drop table faculty;

create table faculty(
  facul_id number not null
 ,faculty_name varchar2(20 char)
 ,constraint pk_faculty primary key (facul_id)
);

create table student(
  st_id number not null
 ,faculty_of_student number
 ,student_name varchar2(20 char)
 ,student_surname varchar2(20 char)
 ,student_email varchar2(20 char)
 ,constraint pk_student primary key (st_id)
 ,constraint fk_student$faculty_of_student foreign key (faculty_of_student) references faculty (facul_id)
);
```